# Understanding how $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is a Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm currently doing work on discrete mathematics in my free time and am having some difficulties with understanding Boolean algebra. To be specific, I'm stuck on the following practice question:

> Let $A = \{a, b\}$ and list the four elements of the power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$. We consider the operation $+$ to be $\cup$, $\cdot$ to be $\cap$, and complement to be set complement. Consider $1$ to be $A$ and $0$ to be $∅$.
>
> 1. Explain why the description above defines a Boolean algebra.
> 2. Find two elements $x$, $y$ in $\mathcal{P}(A)$ such that $xy = 0$, $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$.

Starting with the power set: $$\mathcal{P}(A) = \{∅, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}.$$

How would I go about finding the elements of $x$ and $y$ to satisfy part two of the question using algebraic axioms? Also, for explaining how the above defines a Boolean algebra, do you think it would suffice to simply mention how there are two binary operations and a set associated with the Boolean algebra?

Comment: Can you describe the "multiplication" in words?

Comment: I would assume so. Would that make the solution that much easier to find/prove?

Comment: I would start by trying the various options.

Comment: I think it would make finding $x \neq \varnothing \neq y$ with $x \cdot y = 0$ easier, yes.

Comment: are x and y necessarily distinct?

Comment: @Jon: Consider the definitions of $0$ and of $\cdot$ in this case. If $x,y\ne\emptyset$ are such that $x\cdot y=0,$ then ***are*** $x,y$ necessarily distinct?

Comment: @CameronBuie; that's what I was thinking - perhaps they are not distinct

Comment: @Jon: Did you try it?

Comment: @CameronBuie; try what?

Comment: @Jon: Figuring out if $x\cdot x=0$ for some $x\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: @CameronBuie; does it?

Comment: @Jon: Does what? Be specific.

Comment: @CameronBuie; its okay - i figured it out

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\{a\}$ and $y=\{b\}$. We have $x\ne\emptyset$ and $y\ne\emptyset$. We also have $xy=x\cap y=\{a\}\cap\{b\}=\emptyset=0$, so that seems to work.

A [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) has variables that can **only** be true or false (or $1$ or $0$). Normal algebraic operations can continue as usual, unless of course they don't work.

Comment: +1: Excellent! Now you need only prove that/explain why the Boolean algebra axioms hold on the given structure.

Comment: As a bonus problem: you should be able to prove that we can replace the given set $A$ with *any* set, define the operations the same way, and still get a Boolean algebra. This is because Boolean algebras were pretty much *invented* as generalizations of power sets under intersection and union.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Concrete_Boolean_algebras

Comment: /sigh/ Yes, of course you could just look it up, but that won't necessarily help you get a feel for anything.

Comment: i should do, but before i got into this question, i was going to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratrix

Answer (score 1):

A boolean algebra is any set together with two binary operation $\land$ and $\lor$, one unary operation $\lnot$ and two nullary operations $0$ and $1$ (that is, **two constants**) satisfying a suitable set of axioms - see, for instance, [the definition section from the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29#Definition).

The simplest boolean algebra is the already mentioned two element set $\{0,1\}$ together with the traditional truth table operations, but - as you seem to know already - any set $S$ gives rise to a boolean algebra defined on its power set $\mathcal{P}(S)$: just define $\land, \lor, \lnot, 0$ and $1$ to be $\cap, \cup, S\setminus, \emptyset$ and $S$ respectively ($S\setminus$ means complement with relation to $S$).

As for proving that something is indeed a boolean algebra, there's no free lunch. You must check that the definitions you give for the boolean operations satisfy the axioms. So besides *mentioning* that there are two binary operations, you must be sure to have them properly *defined* so that anyone can understand what you take them to be. Also you must define the other operations as well and verify that the axioms hold for them.

For instance, one axiom says that:

$a \land \lnot a = 0$

To show that your particular instance of boolean algebra satisfies this axiom, you must show that:

$a \cap (S\setminus a) = \emptyset$.